# Navigation between more than two views without changing content in textfield

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I've created 3 views in each i've one textfield in which i enter something and move from first to second and then to third and back to first but i want the same first page to be displayed with same content in textfield before navigating i.e. the meaning is that i want to swap between 3 views instead of creating views as how we remove the view and we get view beneath it same as it is, same should happen when i move from third to one.
Can somebody help in getting this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For each view store the taxtfield value in appDelegate,
On ViewDidLoad access the appDelegate value and place it accordingly...